# undefined reference, even when the linked library does exist

Tags: linux, linker, ld

I'm trying to compile VTK from source and I received the following error. I'm running Fedora 27, kernel version 4.14.11-300.fc27.x86_64

```
/usr/lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
/usr/lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0'
```

`ldd /usr/lib64/libSM.so` shows

```
 $ldd /usr/lib64/libSM.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd4998b000)
    libICE.so.6 => /lib64/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f3aa36ff000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f3aa34fa000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3aa3115000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3aa3b23000)
```

Further looking at the symbols in libuuid.so.1 shows

```
$objdump -T /lib64/libuuid.so.1 | grep 'uuid_generate$'
0000000000002370 g    DF .text  0000000000000087  UUID_1.0    uuid_generate

$objdump -T /lib64/libuuid.so.1 | grep 'uuid_unparse_lower'
0000000000002710 g    DF .text  0000000000000002  UUID_1.0    uuid_unparse_lower
```

The output of `ldconfig` is

```
$sudo ldconfig -p | grep libuuid

libuuid.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libuuid.so.1
    libuuid.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/libuuid.so.1


$ sudo ldconfig -p | grep libSM
    libSM.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libSM.so.6
    libSM.so.6 (libc6) => /lib/libSM.so.6
    libSM.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libSM.so
```

I'm not sure, what is going on here. Can someone please help?

Thank you
Senthil

Comment: ? How about `# dnf install python2-vtk*` : Provides version 7.1.1 . http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/27/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/p/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a -luuid to the link. According to my understanding of *.so files you shouldn't have to do that, but in my case it fixes a similar problem.

Comment: You *as a user* shouldn't have to do that when building. However, it is required in the linking command (only libc is implicitly linked). The build system should take care of it at some level, though. If it didn't, then there's a bug somewhere.